# Search a keyword and throw an "not found" error when no results were found

Tags: php

I want to search a keyword with the use of the MySQL's `LIKE` clause (for example: `LIKE %$keyword%`) and then get the result back. If there are no results, i want to show some error message.

I have a table named `ads_post` and i'm searching for the keyword in the fields named `cat_name` and `city_name`.

Could someone help me with this?

---

**search-result.php**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $keyword = $_GET['keywoed'];
        $query = "select * from ads_post where cat_name like '%$keywoed%' or city_name like '%$keywoed%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "cat Name: " . $row["cat_name"] . "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    } 
?>
```

**HTML form code**

```
<form action="search-result.php" method="get" >
    <input class="form-control"  name="keyword" placeholder="Search any keyword..?">
    <input type="submit"   value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: typo, replace `like '%$keywoed%' ` with `like '%$keyword%' ` also, `$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];` Rather than typing field names, just copy them from respective files to avoid typos.

Comment: try `$_GET['keyword']` instead of `$_GET[keywoed]`.

Comment: It is clearly just a typographical error in the question.

Comment: allwase 0 found the result

Comment: Whereas Delhi has been used very often in the Cat_Name field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i catch something

```
$query = "select * from ads_post where cat_name like '%$keywoed%' or city_name like '%$keywoed%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

first defined $query but mysqli_query is $sql please replace $query not $sql :)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: i am so glad @amit happy coding

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
$query = "select * from ads_post where cat_name like '%$keywoed%' or city_name like '%$keywoed%'";
```

with

```
   $query = "select * from ads_post where cat_name like '%$keyword%' or city_name like '%$keyword%'";
```

and other

```
$keyword = $_GET['keywoed'];
```

with replace

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
```

Comment: yes sir i am replace this code but Whereas Delhi has been used very often in the Cat_Name field

Comment: but allwase 0 found the result

Comment: Is there really something in the database that you typed in the search field?

Comment: is first letter is capital 'D' ?

Comment: Can I share the link with you sir